# Inverse div on change radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to inverse two div inside a bigger div when the user choose something on an input radio.

I have this html:

```
<input type="radio" name="orderBy" id="orderByAsc" value="asc" >
<input type="radio" name="orderBy" id="orderByDesc" value="desc" >
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="tags">
        //Stuff inside
    </div>
    <div class="tagsDifficile">
        //Stuff inside
    </div>
</div>
```

So i have tried something like that in javascript:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function (){
    valueRadio = this.value;
    $('.col-md-10 > div').each(function() {
        if(valueRadio == 'asc'){
            $(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);
        }else{
            $(this).appendTo(this.parentNode);
        }
    });
});
```

But it's not working and when i click on the radio desc, the div do not move. 
It's working when i click on the radio asc, but nothing on desc.
Your help would be very appreciate. Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Can i know why the downvote please ?

Comment: Would you be open to a pure CSS solution?

Comment: @Shaggy yes if it's possible in CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input[name=orderBy]', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var val = that.val();
  var wrp = $('#wrp');
  var one = $('#one');
  var two = $('#two');
  if (val == 'desc') {
    var oneC = one.clone();
    one.remove();
    two.before(oneC);
  } else if (val == 'asc') {
    var twoC = two.clone();
    two.remove();
    one.before(twoC);
  }
});
```

```css
.tags {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
}
#one { background-color:green }
#two { background-color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Asc: <input type="radio" name="orderBy" id="orderByAsc" value="asc" >
Desc: <input type="radio" name="orderBy" id="orderByDesc" value="desc" >
<div id="wrp" class="col-md-10">
    <div id="one" class="tags">
        //Stuff inside (one)
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="tags">
        //Stuff inside (two)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but i don't want that the div two move when i click on the second input radio in first. In fact, i want that the div one move to the bottom when i click on the radio two and that the div two move to the top when i click on radio one. Don't know if it's more clear ahah

Comment: Check now if this is the case

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you're clicking the radio desc, it trigger the `else` statement which will append the `div` to the end before it's container closing tags, so if it run, it will results in something like this

Start:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="1">1</div>
    <div id="2">2</div>
</div>
```

1st iteration on div#1, the arrangement become

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="2">2</div>
    <div id="1">1</div> //div#1 moved to before the end of the container
</div>
```

then for the 2nd iteration on div#2, the arrangement become

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="1">1</div>
    <div id="2">2</div> //div#2 moved to before the end of the container
</div>
```

which causing it not to show any difference, different with the prepend that move it to the begining of the container, if using the same Start, the 1st iteration on div#1 will be like this

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="1">1</div> //div#1 moved to after the start of the container
    <div id="2">2</div>
</div>
```

and the 2nd iteration on div#2 will result in

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="2">2</div> //div#2 moved to after the start of the container
    <div id="1">1</div>
</div>
```

So if your `div` has been sorted from the start, you can just use the `$(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);` whether for the Ascending or Descending

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be accomplished with CSS alone, no need for any Javascript. What we're going to do is use flexbox to layout the divs and then, using a `:checked` pseudo class and an adjacent selector `~`, change the `order` of the child divs.

```css
.col-md-10{
    display:-webkit-flex;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow:row wrap;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
}
.col-md-10>div{
    -webkit-flex:1 0 100%;
    flex:1 0 100%;
    width:100%;
}
input#orderByDesc:checked~.col-md-10>div:first-child{
 -webkit-order:2;
 order:2;
}
input#orderByDesc:checked~.col-md-10>div:last-child{
 -webkit-order:1;
 order:1;
}

*{box-sizing:border-box;}
.col-md-10{background:red;margin:10px 0 0;padding:5px 10px;}
.col-md-10>div{background:green;margin:5px 0;padding:20px;}
```

```html
<input checked="checked" type="radio" name="orderBy" id="orderByAsc" value="asc" > Asc
<input type="radio" name="orderBy" id="orderByDesc" value="desc" > Desc
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="tags">
        Box 1
    </div>
    <div class="tagsDifficile">
        Box 2
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** If you have many child divs and don't fancy writing CSS to change the order of every single one, you could change the `flex-direction` of the parent div to `row-reverse` instead:

```
input#orderByDesc:checked~.col-md-10{
    flex-flow:row-reverse wrap;
}
```

- [More information on flexbox on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)
- [More information on flexbox on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [More information on adjacent selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)
- [More information on `:checked` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)

Comment: i gonna look more about flexbox it's nice. But the radio need to be checked ?

Comment: You mean the `checked` attribute I gave the asc radio? No, that's not strictly necessary. However, personally, I'd suggest you do it as it helps to illustrate the initial state of your list.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want it to do, when you click on desc? Because right now, it won't change the order at all, you select each div and append it to its parent, so you put it exactly where it was at the beginning. If you want to change the order by clicking on desc too, just use prepend in both cases. E.g.:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function (){
    $('.col-md-10 > div').each(function() {
        $(this).prependTo($(this).parent());
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4uakama/1/)

Comment: in fact i want that when i click on desc the second div goes after the first one and when i click on asc that it goes to the top. thank for your answer